# Java 8 Optionals, Combining Statements

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, option-type, simplify

I'm new to Java 8 optionals and I'm wondering if there is a way to combine these two statements into one while retaining the optional?

```
public List<String> getEmployeeStreetNames(Employee employee){
     List<Addresses> addresses = Optional.ofNullable(employee)
     .map(Employee::getAddresses)
      .orElse(new ArrayList<>());

   return addresses.stream()
       .map(Address::getStreetName)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I'd note is that in a case like this I wouldn't use `Optional.ofNullable` and might not use `Optional` at all. I'd simply say "you can't call this on a null employee, silly" and let the NPE happen; if `employee.addresses` isn't allowed to be null (e.g., you use the sensible rule that it can be empty but not null) then you can simply start this whole business on `employee.getAddresses().stream()`.

Comment: @chrslis-cautiouslyoptimistic I suggest you make an Answer of your wise Comment,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, avoid creating new objects in "maybe" pipeline steps like `orElse`; you always incur the overhead of creating the parameter even if it's unused. Prefer signatures like `Supplier<T>` or, in this case, `Collections.emptyList()`. (This is *especially* important for exceptions; always use `MyException::new` or `() -> new MyException(foo)`.)

In this case there are a couple of ways to handle the pipeline, either nested or consecutive.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(employee)
    .map(Employee::getAddresses)
    .map(a -> a.stream().map(Address::getStreetName).collect(toList()))
    .orElse(emptyList());

return Optional.ofNullable(employee)
    .map(Employee::getAddresses)
    .orElse(emptyList())
    .stream()
    .map(Address::getStreetName)
    .collect(toList());
```

I'd generally go with the nested version, since the nested pipeline isn't at all difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks much! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Or with Java 9: `Stream.ofNullable(employee) .flatMap(e -> e.getAddresses().stream()) .map(Address::getStreetName) .collect(toList());` (assuming that `getAddresses()` does never return `null`).